# selenium unable to find element button

Tags: c#, selenium, element

i am trying to get this button with selenium in c#

```
<a id="1|0AqnCSdkjQ0|none" href="" target="_self" rel="nofollow" class="download_link 1">Download</a>
```

i tried with id and class but it didn't work.

Here is the web page:
http://www.mp3juices.cc/ - > on the next page

Comment: it is generating the id so i think it is not possible to get it

Comment: i tried with class "download_link 2" and i am getting this error : Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing with that "Compound class" error because you are, basically, asking for two class names.
The button has the class `download_link`.

If you do something like `driver.findElements(By.className("download_link"))` you'll get a List of all the buttons, and get whichever you wanted.

(The above snippet is Java, so you may have to adapt it to C#)

Comment: i did like this:
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("download_link"));
links[0].Click();
getting this error:
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection
means links are null

Comment: Are you sure that the button is visible at this point of execution? There may be no buttons rendered at such time. You may use `new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("download_link"))` before using the `FindElements`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as a solution

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='download_link 1'] and contains(text(),'Download')"));
```

Comment: Additional information: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@class='download_link 1'] and contains(text(),'Download') because of the following error:

Comment: what i found out in css class name can't have space  :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.download_link.2")
```

When you tried to use "download_link 2" you were requesting two class names. You can specify two class names (or more) in a CSS Selector and put a period between them. The CSS selector above is read as find an `A` tag with class `download_link` *and* class `2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        try
        {
            IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return d.FindElement(By.ClassName("dl_link 1"));
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }


        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lists = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("download_link"));
        lists[0].Click();
```

*The code is not optimized, but it works great. (First part i am using to wait for the button to be loaded).

Comment: You should look into [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_WebDriverWait.htm), e.g. `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(someElement));`